# What are the limits to code generation from XML Schema in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, code-generation

I've seen several questions regarding problems with generating classes from XML Schema using `xsd.exe`, along with suggestions for how to pre-process the schema (often using XSLT) to resolve some of the trickier aspects prior to generation. My question is whether it's possible to construct a C# code generator that is 100% compliant with XML Schema. Are the problems with `xsd.exe` merely a question of its implementation, or do they point to a fundamental inconsistency between XML Schema and C#?

**In particular**, I'm interested in how to map concepts in XML Schema to C# - what are the accepted mappings, which mappings are debatable, are there XML Schema constructs that are inherently un-mappable and are there C# constructs that are underutilised? Is there a compliance specification that would provide rules for mapping, such that it could be implemented and tested?

EDIT: For the sake of clarity I'm fully aware that XML Schema won't provide me with fully implemented C# interfaces, I'm interested in whether it can be fully mapped to a C# class hierarchy.

EDIT 2: I've added a small bounty, as I'm interested in getting a bit more detail.

EDIT 3: Bounty still open, but so far heading toward stakx - a good answer but *mainly* dealing with how to replicate C# structures in XML Schema, rather than the other way round. Good input though.

Comment: @marc_s - I was more interested in the opposite direction, XML Schema -> C#, I wasn't expecting to be able use XML Schema as a programming language!

Comment: xsd.exe does not fully map all the xml schema conventions. In addition, certain mappings are less than perfect - for instance the <choice> element.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Interesting question. Not too long ago, I was wondering about exactly the same thing.

I will show a couple examples of how far I got. My demonstration will not be complete (considering that the XML Schema specification is fairly comprehensive), but it should suffice to show...

- that **you *can* do better than `xsd.exe`** (if you're willing to adhere to certain patterns when you write your XML Schema); and
- that **XML Schema allows type declarations that cannot be expressed in C#**. This should not come as a big surprise, considering that XML and C# are very different languages with quite different purposes.

### Declaring an interface in XML Schema

C# interfaces can be defined in XML Schema with complex types. For example:

```
<xsd:complexType name="IFoo" abstract="true">
  <xsd:attribute name="Bar" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
  <xsd:attribute name="Baz" type="xsd:int" use="optional" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

corresponds fairly well to:

```
interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
    int?   Baz { get; set; }
}
```

The pattern here is that abstract and named (non-anonymous) complex types are basically the XML Schema equivalent of interfaces in C#.

Note some problems with the mapping:

- C# access modifiers such as `public`, `internal` etc. cannot be rendered in XML Schema.
- You have no way of expressing the difference between a C# field and a property in XML Schema.
- You cannot define methods in XML Schema.
- You also have no way of expressing the difference between a C# `struct` and `class`. (There's simply types in XML Schema, which roughly correspond to .NET value types; but they're much more restricted in XML Schema than complex types.)
- The usage of `usage="optional"` can be used to map nullable types. In XML Schema, you could define a string attribute as optional. Crossing over to C#, some loss in translation occurs: Since `string` is a reference type, it cannot be declared as nullable (since it's already nullable by default).
- XML Schema also allows `usage="prohibited"`. This is again something that cannot be expressed in C#, or at least in a nice fashion (AFAIK).
- From my experiments, it appears that `xsd.exe` will *never* generate C# interfaces from abstract complex types; it will stay with `abstract class`es instead. (I'm guessing that this is to keep the translation logic reasonably simple.)

### Declaring abstract classes

Abstract classes can be done very similarly to interfaces:

```
<xsd:element name="FooBase" abstract="true">
  <xsd:complexType>
    ...
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Here, you define an element with the `abstract` attribute set to `true`, and embed an anonymous complex type inside it.

This corresponds to the following type declaration in C#:

```
abstract class FooBase { ... }
```

### Declaring classes

As above, but omit the `abstract="true"`.

### Declaring classes that implement an interface

```
<xsd:complexType name="IFoo" abstract="true">
  ...
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Foo" type="IFoo" />
```

This maps to:

```
interface IFoo { ... }

class Foo : IFoo { ... }
```

That is, you define both a named, abstract complex type (the interface), and a named element with that type.

- Note that the C# code snippet above contains `...` twice, while the XML Schema snippet has only one `...`. How come?

  Because you cannot define methods (code), and because you also cannot specify access modifiers, you don't need to "implement" a complex type with the element in XML Schema. The "implementation" of the complex type would be identical to the original declaration. If the complex type defines some attributes, these simply get mapped to auto-properties in a C# interface implementation.

### Expressing inheritance relationships in XML Schema

Class and interface inheritance in XML Schema can be defined through a combination of type extensions and element substitution groups:

```
<xsd:element name="Base" type="base" />
<xsd:element name="Derived" substitutionGroup="Base" type="derived" />
                       <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->

<xsd:complexType name="base">
  <xsd:attribute name="Foo" type="xsd:boolean" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="derived">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="base">  <!-- !!! -->
      <xsd:attribute name="Bar" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This maps to:

```
class Base
{
    bool Foo { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Note:

- We're again using named complex types. But this time, they're not defined `abstract="true"`, since we're not defining any C# interface type.
- Note the references: Element `Derived` is in `Base`'s substitution group; at the same time, complex type `derived` is an extension of complex type `base`. `Derived` has type `derived`, `Base` has type `base`.
- Named complex types that are not abstract have no direct counterpart in C#. They're not classes, since they cannot be instantiated (in XML, *elements*, not *types*, have roughly the same function as value constructors in F# or object instantiation in C#); neither are they truly interfaces, since they are not declared abstract.

### Some things that I haven't covered in my answer

- Showing how one would declare, in XML Schema, a C# class type that implements *several* interfaces.
- Showing how complex content in XML Schema maps to C# (my first guess it that there's no correspondence in C# at all; at least not in the general case).
- `enum`s. (They are realised in XML Schema by restricting a simple type via `enumeration`, btw.)
- `const` fields in a class (these would possibly map to attributes with a `fixed` value).
- How to map `xsd:choice`, `xsd:sequence` to C#; How to correctly map `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>`, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to XML Schema?
- XML Schema simple types, which sound like they're the corresponding concept of .NET value types; but are far more restricted and have a different purpose.

There's many many more things that I haven't shown, but by now you can probably see the basic patterns behind my examples.

To do all this correctly, one would have to systematically go through the XML Schema specification and see how each concept mentioned there maps *best* to C#. (There's perhaps no single best solution, but several alternatives.) But I explicitly meant to show only a couple of interesting examples. I hope that was still informative enough!

Comment: An interesting answer, which deals with a lot of the thoughts I had, though from the opposite perspective (C# => XML Schema rather than XML Schema => C#). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a limit to code generation. It's that XML schema does not describe classes. It describes XML, which is a different thing.

The result is that there is an "impedance mismatch" between XML Schema and C# classes, or Java classes, or any other kind of classes. The two are not equivalent, and are not meant to be.

Comment: And yet it's common to use XML Schema to provide a code outline. Clearly we can't use XML Schema to provide an interface as such, I'm not interested in trying to replicate C# in XML Schema. I'm interested in where a possible conceptual mapping from XML Schema to C# might fall apart. In other words, is the impedance mismatch only one way?

Comment: @James: how would you map `xs:choice` or mixed content?

Comment: @John Saunders - that was pretty much my question to begin with! Mixed content is only a "slightly" special case in that it's a sequence of text nodes and child elements.

Comment: @James: how would you map it to OO? You would have to use `IEnumerable<XNode>` or something equally useless. There's no useful mapping.

Comment: @John Saunders - I'm not actually arguing the other side, but I'm interested in what people might want out of schema - code generation and whether it can provide it. I'm pretty much in agreement with you, but I'm looking for a more detailed answer so I might offer a small bounty (not got all that much rep to spare...) You're more than welcome to flesh out your answer a little:-)

Comment: @James: I suggest you go learn XML Schema in more detail before asking. You may find the answer is pretty obvious - they're two different things and do not map to each other.

Comment: @John Saunders: that's just a tiny bit patronising. If it's so utterly pointless then why are so many people doing it, and why are there so many tools for it? And given that there's so much of it about, would a good clear answer on SO not be a good idea? And no, I'm not doing any XML Schema based code generation myself.

Comment: @James: you asked a broader question. Yes, there are subsets of XML Schema that map to subsets of OO. People are "doing" those subsets. You asked the more general question, and the answer is: go learn XML Schema, and when you're done, you'll know why only subsets work.

Comment: @John Saunders: please stop telling me to go and learn XML Schema, I've plenty of experience with it, without being able top quote the whole spec word for word. My C# skills are fairly basic though, which is why I asked. You'll notice the wording of the question was "is it possible", not "would it be useful or pretty". The question was general, but also asked for specific details of precisely what the subset of XML Schema that could be mapped to C# was, and which specifically couldn't. The answer might be obvious to you, but it might not be to everyone, which is the basic premiss of SO.

Comment: @James: the answer from someone who has had to deal with the XML Serializer and answering questions about the XML Serializer for the  past several years is, "forget it". If you ask one of the Microsoft developers who wrote the XML Serializer, you might get a long dissertation on what the differences are. It would amount to "forget it".

Comment: @John Saunders: I appreciate your expertise in the area and the advice to forget it won't be hard to follow, as I wasn't ever going to attempt it to begin with :-) I'm still interested in the long dissertation though!